# pip install packages in wrong directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm خn windows 10 and using pyhcarm community edition 2020
when i install a package using pip  it works and put the package into the directory `"C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages"`
now trying to import the package get error `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named <package name>"`

I tried to install the package I want from the setting > project > project interpreter
and it works but only for the projects that I'm working on
also tried to copy the package from the directory that I mentioned before to the directory `"C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib"`

and seems to be working in every projects just as I hope
but don't want to have to copy every package I install by this way so I think I need to change the default directory of installing packages from pip
note : I tried getting to the environment variables and change the path but didn't word and I'm not sure what I should change it to

Comment: what is the active interpreter of pycharm? It is on the bottom right of the ide.

Comment: @LiorCohen Python 3.9(<name of my project>)
when I click on it shows Python 3.9(<venv>), tried to change it and still getting the eror
tried to check the interpreter settings and notices that names of all my projects are avalable to use as interpreters

Comment: so it looks you are using virtual env but performing your pip on the system python. call pip from pycharm terminal or better go to interpreter settings and add the package.

Comment: I think you're totally right, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should provide target path to pip by "-t" tag just like

pip install package_name -t C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib